# O que é pior um "where" ou "join"? Qual é mais custoso?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, desempenho

O que é pior um `where` ou `join`? Qual é mais custoso?

Comment: Adicione um contexto a sua pergunta.

Comment: -1 "que e mais costoso" ????????

Comment: um (des)like ;)

Comment: o melhor é dar um negativo

Comment: se estiver se referindo a `FROM tabA JOIN tabB on tabA.id - tabB.id` e `FROM tabA, tabB WHERE tabA.id = tabB.id`, ambos são `JOINS`, porem o primeiro é explicito e o segundo é implicito, devem gerar o mesmo plano de execução, por tanto o mesmo desempenho, porém o explicito tem a vantagem de ser mais legivel.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 4):

No fundo um `join` funcionará através de buscas da forma como o `where` é feito. Como esse `where` será montado depende do analisador do SQL do banco de dados em questão. O analisador pode ser melhor ou pior de acordo com o fornecedor e isto poderá dar otimizações melhores ou piores dependendo da situação. Não existe mágica.

Um `where` simples certamente é menos custoso. Um `where` que faz relações entre duas ou mais tabelas pode ter o mesmo custo do `join`, depende de como ele é escrito. Se o programador for bem esperto e a situação permitir ele **poderá** fazer um `where` que faça o mesmo que um determinado `join` faria de forma mais eficiente. Se o programador não for tão bom, tem uma boa chance de ele escrever um `where` para obter o mesmo resultado que seja pior que um `join`.

Se tiver um caso concreto, escreva com `join` e escreve outra com `where`, faça o teste e chegue a uma conclusão, é a única forma de garantir isto. Mesmo que tenha muita experiência e acredite que tem boa intuição (que é experiente de verdade nunca acredito nisto), ainda não deve confiar nela, deve testar.

Mande um comando `excute plan`, `explain` ou algo assim.

Este exemplo provavelmente produzirá resultados iguais na maioria dos banco de dados:

```
SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.ID = b.ID;
 
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/JoinNoJoin.sql).

Em um melhor contexto a resposta poderia ser melhor contextualizada, mas no geral é isto.

Comment: Na verdade a dúvida está aqui: 

- Em uma stored procedure, que executa uma consulta relativamente grande com alguns JOINs e WHEREs agregados, o que seria MELHOR, acrescentar um JOIN nesta consulta ligando uma outra tabela, ou aumentar as condições do WHERE?

Comment: A pergunta que você fez não consta isto, eu respondi o que foi perguntado. Mesmo com esta informação, não ajuda muito, na verdade talvez até atrapalhe porque tenta dar um exemplo, mas sem ser concreto. Não tem como eu ou outra pessoa adivinhar qual é melhor. Na minha resposta diz isto.