# Número de Colunas X desempenho em tabelas

Tags: mysql, desempenho, tabela-html

Estou trabalhando com MySQL 10.x numa tabela que já tem 60 colunas, mas vira e mexe preciso incluir mais colunas, eu costumo desmembrar em varias tabelas justamente para não criar uma tabela muito grande em termos de numero de campos.

Estava lendo sobre os limites no site do MySQL e vi que o numero de campo e tamanho está longe de atingir o limite do MySQL, porém eu costumo evitar tabelas muito grandes

Dúvidas:

Se eu desmembrar muito minhas tabelas não terei mais lentidão nas pesquisas devido ao uso excessivo de `join`s?

Devo criar uma tabela com o máximo de campos que achar necessário sem desmembrar?

Comment: Penso que o número de colunas não afeta de forma relevante o desempenho, desde que seleciones apenas as colunas que precisas, em vez de `SELECT * FROM ...` faz `SELECT col1, col2 FROM...`

Comment: 60 colunas? me parece muito, nem é o ponto de performance em si, mas sua tabela provavelmente está desnormalizada, não consigo pensar numa simples entidade que tenha tantas colunas assim, deveria rever isso do ponto de vista de modelagem. O banco de dados tem mecanismos para ser **relacional**, ou seja, permitir que relacione muita coisa, mas sinceramente fiquei curioso, que 60 colunas seriam essas que precisa de tudo de uma vez numa única query? pode colocar na pergunta? pode ajudar na analise

Comment: Não sei se ajudaria colocar na pergunta, essa tabela vem de um JSON que pego de um webservice, ele vem com "subchaves" onde desmembro em outras tabelas, eu procuro manter a estrutura que vem deles pra não ter problemas quando mudar algo, só na principal tem uns 50 campos, ai tem mais os meus campos de controle ou seja, já nasce grande, e não tenho controle sobre isso, e desmembrar seria o caos na minha base. Minha pergunta é pra ter uma ideia se devo inserir meus campos na mesma tabela, eu penso que se fragmentar muito pode ficar lento.

Comment: MySQL 10.x? Tem certeza? A versão mais recente não é a 8.x?

Comment: No meu Servidor mostra assim: MySQL version: 10.2.36-MariaDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O número de colunas não afeta a performance por si só. É claro que mais dados há um custo maior, mas ele sequer é proporcional, é amortizado, então quanto mais dados está lidando, a tendência (tem exceção) é que o desempenho geral melhore um pouco em vários cenários. O custo pra trazer dois dados tende a ser menor que o dobro do custo de trazer um dado (desconsiderando diferença de tamanho do dado).

Se você tem que lidar com muitos dados então lide, não tem problema, os bancos de dados foram feitos para isso. Se está com dados que não deveria lidar, o que é bem raro alguém fazer algo assim, então aí deveria melhorar isso.

Se separa em várias tabelas está fazendo uma pseudo [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/402541/101) e aí sim é quase certo que terá queda de desempenho, talvez até bem grande porque terá que fazer um `join` de forma ou de outra. Pode ver mais sobre em:

- [O que faz um JOIN ser ruim em banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216855/101)
- [O que é pior um "where" ou "join"? Qual é mais custoso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123554/101)
- [Qual é mais eficiente, realizar várias queries ou usar JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251630/101)

Então começará fazer [relacionamentos um pra um](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253550/101) sem necessidade, tornando tudo mais lento. É o oposto do que imagina. Os dados precisam ser pegos em locais diferentes em vez de serem pegos tudo junto. Deveria ser óbvio isso, até um pedreiro sabe que pegar um tijolo em cada lugar é pior que pegar todos juntos, mas por alguma razão programadores não sabem.

Note que existe um mito sobre trazer todos os campos ser mais lento. Sim, isso costuma ser verdade, mas não é simples assim, e a maioria das pessoas fazem simplificações. Isso pode não ser verdade, ou ser até o oposto, depende muito do cenário. Veja [Por que usar "SELECT * FROM tabela" é ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21583/101). Lendo isso poderá ver que a questão é complexa.

De qualquer forma, muda bem menos do que imagina, e só será relevante em casos extremos. Em geral a pessoa tem um banco de dados ridiculamente pequeno e acha que tem uma das maiores bases de dados do mundo e que precisa de otimizações absurdas.

A decisão de onde colocar os dados deveria ser prioritariamente lógica, fazer o que é certo conceitualmente, isso por si só já deve dar um bom desempenho. Nos casos em que realmente há algum problema real, e não imaginário, aí deve-se se pensar em uma organização fora do comum, pensando na otimização e obter ganhos extraordinários.

60 colunas é bem baixo, realmente tem muitos casos para armazenar tudo isso ou mais. O tamanho dessas colunas afetará muito comais que a quantidade delas. Mas como dito antes, só porque tem mais dados. Dividir não diminui a quantidade de dados.

Parece que o problema pede campos juntos em uma tabela por questão lógica e de desempenho.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Maniero, eu sei que é complicado dar uma resposta direta por várias questões, mas na sua opinião, devo criar em uma tabela só quantos campos forem necessários quando os dados não exigem 1 para N? Depois de ler sua resposta e outras matérias penso que enquanto os dados não dão origem a "filhos" tipo Pedido -> Ítens devo manter tudo numa mesma tabela.

Comment: Sim, é o que está na resposta.