# Guardar dados no DB na vertical ou horizontal?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados

Recentemente postei uma questão sobre quantidade de campos em uma tabela aqui: [Numero de Colunas X desempenho em tabelas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/489808/numero-de-colunas-x-desempenho-em-tabelas)

Agora me curiosidade sobre a normatização na criação da tabela abaixo, tenho a seguinte situação:

Tabela de Planos:

Exemplo 1: (como as vezes vejo)

```
create table planos(
  pl_codkey (primary),
  pl_nome_plano varchar(80),
  pl_parcela_1 decimal(12,2),
  pl_parcela_2 decimal(12,2),
  pl_parcela_3 decimal(12,2),
  pl_parcela_4 decimal(12,2),
  pl_parcela_5 decimal(12,2),
  pl_parcela_6 decimal(12,2),
  etc.
)
```

Observações exemplo 1: Temos que criar o SQL conforme a parcela (coluna) procurada, eu vejo duas formas 1: encher o sistema de `if`s/`case`s ou concatenar o numero da parcela no nome da coluna ao criar a string SQL, temos outro detalhe se precisamos de mais parcelas temos que adicionar mais campos, imagino um plano de imóvel onde temos 180 parcelas ou mais.

Vantagem no exemplo 1: guardo os dados numa única linha.
Desvantagem: O tratamento para a pesquisa e exibição dos dados exige mais programação e necessidade de mexer na base caso precise adicionar mais campos, a menos que já crie uma tabela com 500 campos :-).

Exemplo 2 (como faço)

```
create table planos(
  pl_codkey (primary),
  pl_nome_plano varchar(80),
  pl_parcela int,
  pl_taxa decimal(12,2)
)
```

Observações exemplo 2: Faço a pesquisa pelo `pl_codkey` e parcela

No exemplo 2 temos a facilidade na pesquisa e elaboração da tabela, pois não importa o numero de parcelas o banco já está preparado.

Vantagem: Não exige manutenção da estrutura da tabela

Desvantagem: Exige um pouco de atenção caso trabalhe com Grupos de Planos, teremos mais registros conforme o numero de parcelas e planos.

Agora pensando:

Imagine inserir 1000 clientes com planos de 36 parcelas, teríamos 36 mil linhas com 4 colunas e no exemplo 1 e teríamos 1000 linhas com 36 colunas.

Fico me perguntando se no exemplo 2 posso ter lentidão mais rápido do que no exemplo 1 ao longo do tempo

Comment: eu editei a minha resposta sobre um detalhe importante sobre ter id do plano (pl_codkey ) e parcela na mesma tabela, isso vai dar problema ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambos podem ser usados, claro. Um deles é o formalmente correto, o outro pode dar mais eficiência no sistema, além das diferenças já observadas pelo autor da pergunta.

## Uma só tabela, várias linhas (errado)

Do ponto de vista de [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101), entre os apresentados, o segundo modelo parece ser o mais adequado. Na verdade é bastante possível que nem ele seja o certo, ou seja, eu tenho quase certeza que estritamente o segundo é errado.

## Duas tabelas relacionadas (formalmente correto)

Provavelmente o certo seria um terceira forma mantendo essa tabela de planos sem as parcelas e ter uma tabela auxiliar só com as parcelas. Eu não posso afirmar se isso é o mais correto porque não conheço o problema real todo e o exemplo mostrado é artificial para fazer tal afirmação, embora há indícios que o mais correto seria a tabela auxiliar. A segunda forma não atende a normalização correta, e já quebra a primeira forma normal (entre as 6 conhecidas atualmente).

A normalização indica que você não pode ter informações redundantes, nem ter informações sem preenchimento. Então se você tiver linhas cujos campos tenham a mesma informação (não por coincidência) está sendo redundante. `pl_nome_plano` é claramente redundante, você não pode criar várias linhas com essa mesma informação sendo que ela deveria ser única, está pensando criar muitas linhas para um único item, isto fere a normalização e cria dificuldades. Portanto o segundo modelo seria não só inadequado, como formalmente errado. Apenas se adaptá-lo para a tabela auxiliar é que ele seria correto, e dependendo da situação seria adequado.

## Uma só tabela, vários campos (aceitável)

O primeiro caso pode ser perfeitamente aceitável como exceção da regra, já que apesar de estar formalmente errado, não cria problemas graves, e pode compensar o seu uso se precisar de eficiência (nem sempre precisa). O correto deve ser prioridade.

Se estiver tudo em uma só tabela, em uma só linha poderá pegar os dados com menos esforço no banco de dados e isso é útil em alguns cenários. A grande desvantagem disso é que precisa ter um campo para cada parcela possível e em boa parte dos casos muitas dessas parcelas serão nulas, o que ocupará algum espaço (alguns DBs tem um custo bem baixo, depende da implementação de cada um, mas para um volume grande de campos haverá desperdício de espaço).

Dependendo do sistema de banco de dados adotado isso poderia ser colocado em um *array* de campos, ou poderia simular esse *array* em um campo de texto ou blob. Não é tão necessário, há vantagens e desvantagens em fazer isso.

Esse modelo tem mais cara de NoSQL (que na verdade é o modelo que ignora relacionamentos).

É mais fácil acessar os dados de forma direta, mas precisa manipulá-los em algumas situações, conforme a pergunta já observa. Mas o modelo relacional não é livre de cuidados, como também é observado, e de fato pode ser até mais trabalhoso dependendo do cenário.

## Conclusão

A quantidade de linhas em si não é problema.

Então para ficar claro, a forma mais rápida tende ser a do primeiro modelo. A do segundo tende ser o segundo melhor caso e a terceira que eu expus usando auxiliar é a só a terceira mais rápida, em condições típicas, o uso de `join` costuma ser o que dá pior performance, por isso criou-se o mito que NoSQL é mais rápido, comparam coisas diferentes. Só a terceira maneira (que eu defini) é a formalmente correta.

O segundo exemplo da pergunta tem um erro na chave primária, faltou incluir o número da parcela nela para dar uma chave única. Seria algo assim:

```
create table planos(
    codkey (primary),
    nome_plano varchar(80)
)

create table planos_parcelas(
    codkey (primary),
    item int (primary),
    valor decimal(12, 2)
)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/ExtraTable.sql).

Note que não precisa de chave estrangeira, isso é desperdício.

Se não quiser violar nenhuma forma normal teria que ser assim. Nem sempre isso deve ser prioridade, em muitos casos eu adotaria o primeiro modelo da pergunta.

Eu ainda não sei se o modelo como um todo está totalmente correto. Ainda é confuso ter valores de parcelas dentro dos planos, pra mim o conceito todo está errado, mas pode ser só falta de informação suficiente, ou nomenclatura errado. Planos não deveriam ter valores, mas se tiver faltou explicação (não que seja relevante para o problema da pergunta, mas pode esconder um erro mais grave na modelagem), ou pode ser que isso não seja um plano, mas o uso do plano, que seja uma conta ou algo parecido. Mas pode ter uma justificativa para ser assim, estou apenas especulando.

Comment: De fato na minha base eu tenho a tabela "auxiliar" (que na verdade é a tabela mãe) que seria a "grupos_planos" e na tabela de planos tenho o grupos_codkey no lugar de pl_nome_plano, eu postei dessa forma justamente para levantar a questão e sugestões como esse sua.

Comment: Não sei bem, mas talvez esse grupo de planos seja gambiarra, ou seja, não seja grupo, de qualquer forma, pelo que está na pergunta ou é grupo ou está pegando o pior dos dois mundos, mantendo tabela auxiliar e redundância.

Comment: Na grupo de planos eu tenho o nome do grupo e a quantidade de parcelas máximas daquele plano, então na tabela plano só entra a quantidade de registros conforme o plano... eu não postei da forma como fiz porque a pergunta se refere a guardar os dados na horizontal ou vertical, mas a sua resposta e dos outros membros mostra que o erro na horizontal seria ter campos em branco a toa quando a quantidade de parcelas não chega ao total de campo.

Comment: Me parece que isso é grupo mesmo, então não é relevante para o problema, mas não confunda isso com a tabela auxiliar. Não é campo em branco, é nulo https://preview.redd.it/0k7yrif7bkg11.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=3e51a116dca547d8207b1e88859d04589404deca, se você tiver o máximo de 360 campos, pode ter 45 bytes de *overhead* em todas as linhas da tabela., por isso uma forma de array ou string/blob poderia ser melhor se adotar essa forma por eficiência. Se tiver poucos campos e poucos ficam em branco, então pode ser algo aceitável, tudo depende do exato problema.

Comment: Lembrando que a performance não deve ser prioridade, mas ela não pode ser negligenciada.

Answer (score 2):

Pela normalização utilizando as formas normals (1F a 5F) o seu primeiro modelo não estaria "corretamente normalizado".

A terceira forma normal (3F), que é a forma que move os campos que são dependentes entre si para outra entidade diz que:

> 3FN define que todos os atributos dessa tabela devem ser funcionalmente independentes uns dos outros, ao mesmo tempo que devem ser dependentes exclusivamente da chave primária da tabela

Fonte: [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalização de dados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados)

Ou seja, você pode ter a parcela 4 sem ter as 3 primeiras? ou ter sómente a 6 só tendo a 1 e 3? Acredito que não, são casos claros de **dependência entre si** das colunas, por isso ela não estaria corretamente normalizada.

A segunda modelagem sim satisfaz a normalização.

Sobre as afirmações sobre a segunda modelagem:

> **Vantagem**: Não exige manutenção da estrutura da tabela
>
> **Desvantagem**: Exige um pouco de atenção caso trabalhe com Grupos de Planos, teremos mais registros conforme o numero de parcelas e planos.

Sobre a desvantagem isso é um fato: quanto mais normalizado estiver o seu modelo, mais entidades vai ter mais segregadas, ou seja, mas independentes e separadas, o que vai exigir mais trabalho ao fazer a query (quanto mais tabelas mais JOINS :) )

Mas tem um contra-argumento em relação ao "teremos mais registros conforme o numero de parcelas", e também terá menos registros desnecessários caso tenha menos parcelas :)

**Mais pontos importantes:**

- A tabela de "planos" é para ter somente dados de planos? Porque se for viola mais ainda a normalização. Deveria ter uma tabela "planos" e outra "parcelas_planos" para satisfazer a 3F (terceira forma normal).
- No seu modelo apenas ter "parcela" vai te dar um problema com a chave primária!

Vejamos um exemplo prático:

```
create table planos(
  pl_codkey (primary),
  pl_nome_plano varchar(80),
  pl_parcela int,
  pl_taxa decimal(12,2)
)

insert into planos(pl_codkey,pl_nome_plano,pl_parcela,pl_taxa )
           values (1, 'Plano 1', 1, 10);
```

Como inserir outra parecela para o mesmo plano? esse comando abaixo vai violar a chave primária ao inserir a segunda parcela para o mesmo plano:

```
insert into planos(pl_codkey,pl_nome_plano,pl_parcela,pl_taxa )
           values (1, 'Plano 1', 2, 12);
```

Ou seja, precisa separar as parcelas dos planos!!!

```
create table planos(
  pl_codkey (primary),
  pl_nome_plano varchar(80)
)

create table planos_parecelas(
    ppp_codkey (primary),
    pl_codkey (foreign key de planos)
    pl_parcela int,
    pl_taxa decimal(12,2)
)
```

E então o insert:

```
insert into planos (pl_codkey,pl_nome_plano)
            values (1, 'Plano 1');

-- aqui as parcelas do 'Plano 1'

insert into planos_parecelas(ppp_codkey,pl_codkey,pl_parcela,pl_taxa)
    values (1, 1, 1, 10);

insert into planos_parecelas(ppp_codkey,pl_codkey,pl_parcela,pl_taxa)
    values (2, 1, 2, 12);
.. etc...
```

**E finalmente sua pergunta:**

> Fico me perguntando se no exemplo 2 posso ter lentidão mais rápido do
> que no exemplo 1 ao longo do tempo

Não, porque na verdade você estaria "otimizando" seu banco de dados para trabalhar com as informações separadas!

Imagina que você quer só saber de planos, se separar planos de parcelas pode fazer select numa tabela com muito menos registros e mais rápida. A tabela que teria parecelas teria muitos registros mas ela tem poucas colunas e seria facilmente filtrada pelas chaves :)

Answer (score -1):

O primeiro modelo é insustentável. Imagine que você projete o banco de dados para suportar até 180 parcelas. Isto é, uma tabela com + de 180 colunas.

1. Qualquer parcelamento que tenha menos do que 180 parcelas implicará em algum desperdício de espaço em disco. Imagine que Zézinho comprou um produto em 10x. Vai ocupar as 10 primeiras colunas - as outras 170 ficarão em branco. Escalando isso pra vários registros, você gasta muito armazenamento, muito rápido.
2. Se eventualmente você quiser suportar parcelamentos maiores (com mais parcelas), precisará alterar o banco de dados.

Com isso, o segundo modelo se mostra mais adequado e flexível. Se houver alguma preocupação quanto à performance de consultar uma tabela com milhares de linhas, você pode normalizar da seguinte forma: numa tabela, você armazena as informações básicas do parcelamento. Isto é: nome do devedor, número de parcelas, etc. Em outra, você armazenará as parcelas de fato, com chave estrangeira apontando para a tabela de parcelamentos.

Assim, você tem um banco de dados mais fácil de manusear, sem sacrificar a performance. Será possível obter rapidamente as informações sobre o parcelamento, e se for necessário saber especificamente sobre as parcelas, basta rodar um único JOIN.